# Get data which is not `null`

Tags: c#, mysql

So i have a class (properties `_id, _title, _note, _issued_in, _accepted_in, _lead_time, _done_in, _difficulity, _worker_fname, _worker_lname`) and some of thoose properties might be `null`.

All i wanna do is get the data from MySQL, which is not `null`. (Because im getting an `Exception` otherwise) The `null` data should be ignored.

I can check every single field by using that;

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("issued_in"))) 
    dummy.issued_in = reader.GetString("issued_in");
```

But is it real to do it faster? I can get field names for example and do it in a loop but there is a problem. I cant define which property to fill

```
foreach (var field in fields) {
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(field.ToString())))
        dummy.// >>>> HERE >>>> done_in = reader.GetString(field.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Rewind a little. What exception do you get and where when any of the fields is null?

Comment: Write a SQL query that returns only non-null values. You haven't posted your query so it's impossible to give a specific answer, but null checks are performed with `somefield IS NULL` and `somefield IS NOT NULL`

Comment: If you get an exception, post the entire exception including its call stack. You can get that with `Exception.ToString()`. Also post the *actual* code that reproduces the error and specify the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i guess OP problem is that he wants to fill an object's properties with the data from the Database, without having to do it one  by one...

Comment: exception is `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException`

Comment: have you tried to change your property types to be `Nullable<T>` or use `?` i.e. `int?` . This may avoid the null value exception.